# Получить byte[ ] из bytea, Postgre SQL и C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, psql

Есть C#-код и подключенная библиотека Npgsql. В БД есть столбец типа bytea, и из него нужно получить byte[].
Вся проблема в том, reader возвращает string, а при переводе этого string'а в byte[] массив меняется. Нужно получить точно такой же массив, какой есть в БД.
Что в БД:

[image: Столбец bytea в psql]

_

Вот код получения массива:

[image: Код получения массива]

_

А вот первые значения массива:

[image: Массив в программе]

Дальнейшая задача - получение этого массива и преобразование в изображение. С массивом из БД работает, с массивом из программы - нет.

Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вот в чём заключалась проблема - ко мне возвращался массив байтов из этого текста:[image]

Как итог, в коде мне нужно написать примерно следующее:

```
byte[] array = reader.GetFieldValue<byte[]>(i);
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
str.Substring(1, str.Lenght-1);
string[] strArray = str.Split(", ");
```

Таким образом, я получу список всех нужных мне байтов, переведённых в string.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `(byte[])reader["columnName"]` или `(byte[])reader.GetValue(i)`, тогда маппинг bytea -> byte[] должен сработать. [Источник](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html?q=json)

Comment: Благодарю вас, попробую)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, к сожалению, указанная вами операцию производит следующие действия: bytea -> bytea.ToString() (каждый символ переводиться в string) -> (byte[])bytea.ToString(). Что-то вроде этого

Comment: Взгляните [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46128864/6468198) и убедитесь, что вы правильно записываете данные в свою таблицу и правильно их читаете. Это преобразование должно работать из-под капота.

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю)

Comment: Да пока не за что благодарить) Если это не поможет, то, возможно, вам нужно будет изменить одну настройку в своей базе данных

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, какую же?

Comment: bytea_output. `SHOW bytea_output;` - попробуйте выполнить эту команду. Оно должно быть равным hex

Comment: Выглядит все так, будто столбец из самой базы возвращается как строка. Либо вы туда записали байты как их строковое представление, либо база по-особому отдает их

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, спасибо!

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, ну и да, столбец возвращается как строка. Не думаю, что я записывал байты как их строковое представление, ибо из этих байтов получается нормальное изображение